# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() is breaking script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing my 1st google app script. Spreadsheet opens a sidebar in `onOpen()`. Sidebar has Button and in **SidebarJavaScript.html** I have listener to that button. I'm calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`  inside listener and after this line script is not executing.

What could possibly be wrong here?

```
function onScrapeClick(){

    // Disable Button
    this.disabled = true;

    // Get Spreadsheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    this.innerHTML ="Clicked";
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

}
```

Button is getting disabled as for line `this.disabled = true;` as expected so lister is working properly for sure.

Comment: you seem to be mixing client-side and server side code. innerHTML is meant to execute on the client where code for manipulating sheets is server side. A few tutorials might be in order. it would be almost impossible to resolve your problem without seeing the entirety of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the method to get data in a `.gs` file and call it with `google.script.run`.

In some `Code.gs` file:

```
function getSheetData()
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   return data;       
}
```

And in the html script:

```
function onScrapeClick(){

  // Disable Button
  this.disabled = true;

  // Get Spreadsheet

  this.innerHTML ="Clicked";
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(
      function(data, element) {
        // code to execute if data was gotten ok
        // the received data is in data argument
      })
    .withFailureHandler(
      function(msg, element) {
        // code to execute if data was not gotten ok
      })
    .getSheetData();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

getValues is a method of the sheet class, you just need to define the active sheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: I tried it. Even after that line script is breaking. After this line I'm trying to change button text and it is not working.