# Implement Google Apps Script to HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to call a Google sheet from within a HTML file. 
This is possible via documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) by:

```
<body>
    <? var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        .getActiveSheet()
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues(); ?>    </body>
```

That really works and catches the values when I load the HTML File.
What I need to do is - I want to set values in a Spreadsheet within a for-loop, which is activated by a button.

```
function processForm() {

var elementsNr = document.getElementsByName("nummerierung")
var elements = document.getElementsByName("schuelername")
var elementsDate = document.getElementsByName("datuminput")
var elementsArt = document.getElementsByName("art")
var elementsZeit = document.getElementsByName("zeit")

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var Nr = elementsNr[i].value;
    var sname = elements[i].value;
    var datum = elementsDate[i].value;
    var Uart = elementsArt[i].value;
    var UZeit = elementsZeit[i].value;

     var data = SpreadsheetApp
                   .openById('1MWy0J5ZKnsXXKWEX72Bh9cRBvsFkDAqTEhW1SxFavmA')
                   .getActiveSheet()
                   .getDataRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5)
                   .getValues([[Nr, datum, sname, Uart, UZeit]]); 
}
```

But somehow I get an reference Error:

> ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined

:(

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The referred documentation is about Templated HTML but the code shown in the question doesn't use the templated HTML syntax. By the other hand, the [Best Practices doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) suggests to load data asynchronally.

To call a server-side Apps Scripts functions from the client-side JavaScript (scripts on an HTML file), first create a function on the .gs file, then call it from the HTML by  using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

For a code example see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30669296/1595451) by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097240/daniel) to [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() is breaking script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651834/spreadsheetapp-getactivespreadsheet-is-breaking-script)

By the way, [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) should not have arguments.

Comment: Thanks ruben - I tried this before but I had big problems because the functions run asynchronious. :/

In the documentation it looks like this way should work too and it would solve all my problems immediately.

Comment: Thanks again Ruben! 

Do you see a way to do it in the way I tried, even if it's not -best practice- ?
I'm quite desperate. I've tried different ways now:

1. trying to give single values from functionINDEXHTML to functionCODEGS - but because of their different speed some data gets lost.

2. trying to give an array from functionINDEXHTML to functionCODEGS -> doesn't work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637258/give-values-of-an-array-to-another-function-js (Error: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0)

3. trying to implement functionB in functionA (this thread)

:'(

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] If you need further help on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow, please post a question on [meta].

Comment: Added a comment to the answer.

Comment: I've asked a specific problem but the solution you gave me leads to other problems which I illustrated. 
My question is quite minimal: how can I implement the code of the documentation in my function...

Comment: Comments are not intended to do folloup questions. Instead you should post a new question. Considering that referred another recent question you made that looks to be about the same "project", in order to avoid to fall in a never ending loop, know as the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378), I think that you should post a better question. Of course, this is up to you. An alternative is to wait for answers from other SO users.